# Could not deduce (Contravariant f) arising from a use of ‘to’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-lens, haskell-optics

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to `transform` the value I got from a Traversal like below

```
startedAt :: Traversal' Object Int
startedAt = ix "at" 
          . (_Integral 
            `failing`  _String . to timeComponent._Right 
            `failing` _String ._Integral)

timeComponent :: Text -> Either String Int
timeComponent t = ...
```

I'm getting this error

```
Could not deduce (Contravariant f) arising from a use of ‘to’
      from the context: Applicative f
        bound by the type signature for:
                   startedAt :: Traversal' Object Int
        at SomeModule/Optics.hs:80:1-34
      Possible fix:
        add (Contravariant f) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            startedAt :: Traversal' Object Int
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘to timeComponent’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘to timeComponent . _Right’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
        ‘to timeComponent . _Right’
```

In other parts of the code, developers are already doing

```
doSomething :: Object -> First Int
doSomething l = First $ <same-code-as-above>
```

As you can see it works when I inline it, but when I move it to a separate Optic like above, it throws error...

Ps: One more doubt, when should I give the type as Traversal instead of Prism?

Comment: It sounds like this is an existing codebase using `lens`, which you may not be able to change; still, for what it’s worth, I find that the error messages when using the [`optics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics) package are often more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your optic is a `Fold Object Int`, not a `Traversal' Object Int`.  If you write the type signature as:

```
startedAt :: Fold Object Int
```

then it will type check.

The underlying problem is that `to f` produces a `Getter`, not a `Traversal'`, and when you compose an optic out of traversals (like `ix "at"`) and getters (like `to timeComponent`), you get a fold.